# Deleting multiple files with special character in file name from perforce

Tags: perforce

I have a directory having 90K files. Lets call the directory as "dir". Many of the filenames has special
character like #, @ etc.

I am looking for a command how can I mark all those files as deleted in perforce.

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters are translated to `%nn` escape codes in the depot namespace, so to operate on those files you need to use the escape code instead of the original character.  (The exception to this rule `p4 add`, which takes the original unescaped name and then escapes it as part of opening the file.)

To operate on all of the files that contain escape codes for `@` (`%40`) and `#` (`%23`) anywhere in their path relative to `dir`, use wildcards:

```
p4 delete dir/...%40...
p4 delete dir/...%23...
```